# How to change listner instance of a button click dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to implement a behavior where i change the button click listener action dynamically based on certain condition. 
So far i have tried below code :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int i =0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(i>0){
            button.setOnClickListener(null);
            buttonsetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // do another function
                }
            });
         }
         i++;
    }
});
```

I have set null on setOnClickListener and then assign a new setOnClickListener to the same button but new assigned listner is not working and still its executing the old setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each onclicklistener create a new instance of that onclicklistener, for example:

```
final View.OnClickListener listener3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
        }
    };


    final View.OnClickListener listener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnNext.setOnClickListener(listener3);
            // do stuff
        }
    };


    View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnNext.setOnClickListener(listener2);
            //do stuff
        }
    };



    btnNext.setOnClickListener(listener1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a new listener, you can write your if-else logic inside the click listener.

```
boolean imageUploaded = false;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int i =0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(imageUploaded){
            //do some stuff.
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
        i++;
    });
}
```

And when the image is uploaded, just set

```
imageUploaded = true;
```

Comment: there is two condition first one is to upload the image and another one is if image is already uploaded then preview an uploaded image.If image already present in server then i have to handle this as well. how to handle this ?

Comment: With a Boolean flag isUploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you click on the button, the first onClickListener is called, and the int i variable is recreated. So it remains equals to zero. Then it doesn't switch to the second onClick listener. Probably you must make your int i variable global.

Comment: thanks for reply. My question is if i changed the listner irrespective of value of i. If new listner is assigned why its not getting called since i have set null first and then assign a new lisnter.

Comment: ok, but as I can see in the code, the change of listener happens ONLY if i>0, condition that never happens.